# Dataframe: Identify percentile values of series, grab corresponding observation's value from other series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame consisting of two columns: `path` and `loss`.

- `path` values are integers from 0 to 300.
- `loss` values are float numbers with a large number of decimal places.

I would like to identify percentile values in `loss`, and then grab the corresponding `path` value.  I used the following code to identify the percentiles:

```
c80 = np.percentile(df['loss']], 80)
```

Then, I have tried a number of failed solutions, most recently:

```
c80_path = df[df['loss'] == c80].path
```

and

```
c80_path = df.loc[df['loss'] == c80,'path']
```

Printing the resultant `c80_path` value returns `"Series([], Name: dtype: int64)"`

I am expecting an integer value between 0 and 300.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentile can (and in this case will) be a value not in the `loss` column. Therefore `df['loss']==c80` yields no results. To find the closest value you can try something as follows:

```py
c80_path = df.iloc[(df['loss']-c80).abs().argsort()[0]]['path']
```